# Custom NSMenu design

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, user-interface, nsmenuitem

Tough question. I'm looking for examples to create a custom NSMenuItem design. I want to achieve something like http://anvilformac.com/. Are there any examples out there that could put me in the right direction? Or at least a tutorial?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for *design* advice, or are you looking for examples of how to *program* a menu with a custom design? Designing and implementing are very different disciplines.

Comment: Guidance on how to program a menu with a custom design

Answer (score 5):

Apple has a [section of their menu programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html) dedicated to this, and the [related sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MenuItemView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004136) provides a full working implementation of a custom menu view.

Comment: What about just doing it in the menu bar? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve design wise https://github.com/gmckenzi/Picker

Comment: @Pxlc: That particular app doesn't use a menu at all. It creates an NSStatusItem (which is how you get an item that lives globally in the menu bar), and when you click on the status item, it brings up a window underneath the status item.

Answer (score 0):

Drag a Custom View into your xib. Right click first Menu item and drag from the view property to the Custom View.